# Как мне отправить ответ на сайт, используя Python?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, webbrowser, captcha

Мне нужно ввести капчу на сайте, я уже получил само изображение капчи, но я не знаю, как вводить текст на сайте с помощью Python.

Код на Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser
r = requests.get("https://анимевост.рф/dw.php?file=MzAzMiU3QzErJUYxJUU1JUYwJUU4JUZGJTdDMjE0NzQyMTk1NQ==")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

img = soup.find_all(class_ = "form_pole_search")

print(img)
rez = img[1]
rez = str(rez)
check = rez.split("src=")
check = check[1]
check = check.split('"')
check = check[1]
url = "https://xn--80aeiluelyj.xn--p1ai/" + check
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Веб-сайт с капчей:

[https://анимевост.рф/dw.php?file=MzAzMiU3QzErJUYxJUU1JUYwJUU4JUZGJTdDMjE0NzQyMTk1NQ](https://xn--80aeiluelyj.xn--p1ai/dw.php?file=MzAzMiU3QzErJUYxJUU1JUYwJUU4JUZGJTdDMjE0NzQyMTk1NQ)

Comment: `Я все еще начинающий программист`, вы Немчинского пересмотрели? ))

Comment: Селенимум вам в помощь